# emr howto access aws credentials in user defined function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

if i run my user defined function that tries to remove a folder from aws

```
private AmazonS3Client s3client = new AmazonS3Client();  

    @Override
    public void deleteObjectsInFolder(String bucketName, String folderPath) {
        for (S3ObjectSummary file : s3client.listObjects(bucketName, folderPath).getObjectSummaries()){           
            s3client.deleteObject(bucketName, file.getKey());
        }
    }
```

using

```
./elastic-mapreduce --create  --bootstrap-action ...
```

it works fine
but when i want to do it using the java sdk i get on my user defined function trying to delete the files

```
2014-08-14 10:03:43,548 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - 
ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error.
Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 95440BF2091119A5,
AWS Error Code: AccessDenied, AWS Error Message: Access Denied
```

what do i need to add to my java code?

Answer (score 0):

Please use code as below

```
private static AmazonS3 s3=null

...

File s3credsFile = new File("AwsCredentials.properties");       
pc = new PropertiesCredentials(s3credsFile);
s3client = new AmazonS3Client(pc);
.....
```

AwsCredentials.properties this should  have your access key and secrete key.

Then only s3client will able to delete files .

Comment: i don't understand why the AmazonS3Client needs the credentials.
I would expect it to be available in the scope, because if i do it using ./elastic-mapreduce the credentials are available. And using 'store' in pig also is able to write to the bucket